# Exceuting a C program that uses LAPACK and BLAS

Tags: c, gcc, lapack

I have a C program "main.c" that uses LAPACK and BLAS subroutines. It is working fine on Ubuntu, showing the right results on the terminal.

Since I am a Windows user, I use Cygwin environment. However, when I execute my program after compiling with **gcc main.c -llapack -lblas -lgfortran** or even **gcc -std=c99 main.c -llapack -lblas -lgfortran**, nothing is showing on the terminal, although there are no compilation errors.

Does anyone have an idea what would be the problem?
Thank you.